# Enable toggle switch only to one item in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, forms, react-hooks

We are using react in our questionnaire in forms. I would like to add the toggle switch to each question to identify the deciding question for a condition. The working should be such that when the toggle is enabled for 1 question, the other questions toggle should be turned off, meaning user should be able to select  only 1 deciding question. Please guide me on how to achieve this? i am stuck

```
                   <Form.Check
                        type="switch"
                        id="decidingQuestion"
                        name="decidingQuestion"
                        value={input.decidingQuestion}
                        checked={input.decidingQuestion}
                        onChange={event => props.handleInputChange(index, event)}
                    >
                    </Form.Check>
```

NOTE: The number of questions will be dynamic based on whether user clicks on "Add" button when they want to add another question.

tried multiple things but did not get the expected results. Not familiar with react and JS.

Addiitonal:

```
const templateRow = { question: '', questionType: '', questionState: '' , decidingQuestion:false};
    const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([templateRow]);
```

```
    const handleInputChange = (index, event) => {
        const values = [...inputFields];
        console.log(event)
        console.log(values)
        if(event.target.name!="decidingQuestion")
            values[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        else{
         if(event.target.checked)
            {
            console.log("INSIDE THIS FIELD")
                values.forEach((x,ind)=>{
                    console.log(x)
                    if(ind!=index){
                        
                        x[event.target.name]=!x[event.target.value]

                    }
                    console.log(x)   
            })}
        values[index][event.target.name]= event.target.checked;
    
    }

        setInputFields(values);
    };
```

Comment: You could possibly use a string to keep track of your selected deciding question. And then a boolean (whether each question === the selected deciding question) for your "checked" property
...
`const [selectedDecidingQuestion, setSelectedDecidingQuestion] = useState<string>("")
...
checked={decidingQuestion === selectedDecidingQuestion}`

Comment: You need to show more code for us to help you. We can't see how you handle some of the variable.

Comment: I have editted the question. Please see now

Comment: he above code i tried is not working :(